# How to write a conditional nested subquery

Tags: sql

I currently use this SQL statement below to examine records in a database and the fields conWkActual, conWkPlanned and conWkBaseline are date values.  The field conWkBaseline always has a value while the other two may be NULL. But if conWkPlanned has a value it is more relevant than conWkBaseline and if conWkActual has a value then it in turn is more relevant than conWkPlanned. What I would like to know is can I have a nested subquery that will only output the most relevant date instead of all three.  For example if all three have a value then determine if conWkActual has a value then output that value only

```
SELECT C.conContractID, C.conWkActual, C.conWkPlanned, C.conWkBaseline, C.conService,  
C.conCapRev, C.conContractType, C.conSection, C.conContractStatus FROM Contracts C
WHERE ConContractStatus = 'Cancelled';
```

Comment: You can use `COALESCE` as mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you need the most relevant date field from the conWkActual, conWkPlanned and conWkBaseline if they are not null. If that's the case then 
`COALESCE` would do the job if You need to get the Not NULL value for most relevant date field

```
  SELECT C.conContractID, COALESCE(C.conWkActual, C.conWkPlanned, C.conWkBaseline) AS 'YourDatecolumn', C.conService,  C.conCapRev, C.conContractType, C.conSection, C.conContractStatus 
  FROM Contracts C
  WHERE ConContractStatus = 'Cancelled';
```

Here is the link for more explanation on `COALESCE` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Am I correct in saying the order the items are listed in the coalesce brackets is important, i.e. in this case conWkActual would be first as it is most relevant?

Comment: Yes, IF you read about `COALESCE` it resolves first value if its `NULL` then it moves on to the  next and if `NOT NULL` then that value get selected.